# Puppet: suppressing notice output from a file type

Tags: puppet

As part of a puppet apply provisioning setup I need to change the owner group and permissions on directory recursively. This is pretty easy to do with puppet's file type:

```
    file { "$appRoot":
      ensure => directory,
      recurse => true,
      owner => 'whoever',
      group => 'thegroup',
    }
```

The problem is that there are tens of thousands of files in this directory, and puppet's notice: logging output writes out to the console or log file three times for each file, notifying that it successfully changed the owner, group, and mode. This leads to unusably large output logs and I'd like to suppress this output unless there was an error.

In the exec type there is an option to do this, logoutput => on_failure or false, but I can't seem to find any way to do this with file. It seems like doing much (or anything) in exec is frowned upon in the puppet world, is there any other way to customize the logging on the file operation short of moving it to an exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place `--logdest /dev/stdout` on the `puppet agent` run. This will put all the logs to stdout. Your log files won't get written and you can listen to the stdout through `egrep` or something similar and only picks up the thing you want, e.g. non-success...

```
 puppet agent <options> --logdest /dev/stdout | egrep -iv "notice" >& /log/dir/logoutput
```

Comment: I think that will work, even though this seems like something that should be built into puppet types.